# Insert external php file into html

Tags: php, html

Insert header and footer with PHP includes in HTML

I am creating a website locally and I would like to insert header and footer in a separate page since they are always the same, but when I insert the php include tag inside the html page where I have to insert it, it doesn't read it to me. On the other hand, if I insert it in another page it reads it to me. Can you guys help me out?
I don't know if I was very clear in my explanation.

### Edit #1

I want to create a site for cinema management. I created the page where I can display the descriptions of the various movies that are produced at the cinema. On each page the header and footer are the same, only the body changes, so I wanted to create the header page separately and embed it in the page mentioned before. How can this be done? I tried using include from php, but it doesn't work. I also tried inserting the link

```
<link href="nome del percorso" rel="import">
```

The page about the description of the various films opens when you click on the "buy now" button.

The file header.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cate Cinema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../page_film/page_film.css">
  <link rel="import" href="../header/header.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">
  <!-- Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Office:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Infant:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Didact+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

  <body id="homepage">
    <!--<include src="../index.php"></include>-->
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="navigation-open">
          <div class="global container grid-x">
            <div class="logowrapper grid-x">
              <div class="logo-container">
                <a href="index.html">
                  <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-nav cell grid-x">
              <nav class="choicewrapper">
                <ul class="wrapper">
                  <li class="page-cinema">
                    <a href="#" class="gradient-fill-hover">
                      <span>A</span>
                      <span>l</span>
                      <span>&nbsp</span>
                      <span>C</span>
                      <span>i</span>
                      <span>n</span>
                      <span>e</span>
                      <span>m</span>
                      <span>a</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="page-card">
                    <a href="#" class="gradient-fill-hover">
                      <span>C</span>
                      <span>a</span>
                      <span>r</span>
                      <span>d</span>
                      <span>&nbsp</span>
                      <span>e</span>
                      <span>&nbsp</span>
                      <span>P</span>
                      <span>r</span>
                      <span>o</span>
                      <span>m</span>
                      <span>o</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="page-pass">
                    <a href="#" class="gradient-fill-hover">
                      <span>P</span>
                      <span>a</span>
                      <span>s</span>
                      <span>s</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <nav class="loginwrapper grid-x cell align-right">
              <div class="form-search-s grid-x">
                <form class="form-search" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" role="search">
                  <label for="search">Search for stuff</label>
                  <input class="input-search" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus required />
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-search" onclick="index.html">Go</button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="profile-login">
                <a href="../login/login.html" title="Accedi / Registrati">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                  <span>Login</span>
                  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="container-login open grid-x">
                  <div class="dropdown-content grid-x cell">
                    <div class="container-dashboard cell d-flex auto">
                      <ul>
                        <li class="list-login">
                          <a href="#" class="login">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <span>Login</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-login">
                          <a href="#" class="registration">
                            <i class="fas fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i>
                            <span>Registrati</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The file prova.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cate Cinema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../page_film/page_film.css">
  <link rel="import" href="../header/header.html">
  <!--<link rel="import" href="../header/header.html" />-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">
  <!-- Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Office:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Infant:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Didact+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>

    <!--<include src="prova2.html"></include> INCLUSIONE CODICE ESTERNO -->
  </body>
</html>
```

### Edit #2

My code index.php is:

```
<?php include './header/header.php'; ?>
```

My code header.html is:

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<include src="../index.php"></include>
my code...
</body>
```

My code prova.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cate Cinema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../page_film/page_film.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <include src="../header/header.html"></include>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: I don't read anywhere in your question that you understand that you can only use the `include` tag inside PHP files. That is, files that end in the `.php` extension.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: PHP needs a server to be rendered. So when you say `locally` do you mean localhost or file system?

Comment: I know that in order to use the include tag I have to put it in a .php file, and I did, but when I run my code it does not read it within the html page.

Comment: I am creating this site locally.

Comment: Your html file needs to be renamed to .php as well. It would really help us to help you, if you show us relevant parts of your code and the names of each of the files- see also the guide to making a [mre] of your issue

Comment: @CaterinaRomano can you alter the extension of prova.html to prova.php so that you can use the pgp `include_once()` function? or mayhe (not as optimal) to make the html server pass `*.html` to the  php interpreter (this will slowdown static html pages a bit if you not have some sort of caching).

otherwise, as has been suggested, you either need to use the html `<iframe>` tag or some extension on the webserver to provide Server side includes (sometimes abbreviated SSI)

Comment: If you're using Apache or IIS then server side includes is an option which does not require you to change your pages to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not offer a `<include>` tag. That does not exist, so that code you have written for it does nothing.

What you need is to have your files all based off PHP (so, they need to have the .php file extension, not .html) [Why? Because you're telling PHP to try to include a `header.php` file, which doesn't exist; your `header` file is a `.html` file.] and then you need a web server for development. You can use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), for example.

Once you have the server running you need to navigate to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as your localhost web address, this will be your web directory. PHP can not execute unless it's run on a server, but a test server like this works fine.

If `index.php` is the file you want to have something included into, you can simply write your `include_once` (preferable over `include`) statement where you want PHP to render it. For example if you want to include a navbar file into your main page:

**index.php**

```php
<body>
<?php include_once('.../path_to_navbar.php');
</body>
```

**header.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cate Cinema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../page_film/page_film.css">
  <!-- you do not need a link statement here for header.php -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">
  <!-- Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Office:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Infant:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Didact+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<!-- TRUNCATED FOR ANSWERING PURPOSES -->
```

Comment: How should I do it with javascript? If I don't want to use PHP

Comment: @CaterinaRomano There really isn't a good way to do it. I mean you could use fetch statements with promises, but it doesn't really have the same amount of 'ease' as PHP's functionality.

Comment: To me, even if you don't use PHP for much else, it's still good to use PHP for a lot of basic things like this, even if you make JavaScript do all of the heavy lifting as an API to handle your back-end. Using it that way is like writing HTML but with extra benefits.

Answer (score -3):

The command to insert one html file into another is "iframe".  The php extensions and code you tried to use were confusing the issue.  See edit to your prova.html file where it is substituted in the line where you had "include".  I added some inline css to make sure your header fully displays.  In my test I had both header.html and prova.html in the same directory, so I don't use file paths.  Play around with the width and height to fit it with the rest of the information that will display on the prova page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cate Cinema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../page_film/page_film.css">
</head>
  <body>
<!--     <include src="../header/header.html"></include> -->
<iframe  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" style="width:325px;height:550px;"  src="header.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you [edit] your answer and elaborate that it is "a html tag to insert" instead of "The command".  it might be more clear.

Comment: The questioner wanted to include the source code into the specific position on the page, I'd assume. They seem to already know what PHP's `include` does, which basically just grabs the source code of the file you want to include and injects it into the page at the DOM position the `include` function is rendered at.

Comment: wrong answer . you must use php to include your template parts in one file. html dos not have this option because it is server as static and webserver do not parse html contents so you need use dynamic language like php